# encoding of metadata from images in subfolders

Tags: python, encoding, metadata

I'm starting in Python and have two problems with a script to read metadata from images starting in a folder and recurring in its subfolders.

first: I only get output from one subfolder
 second: the output of some fields is in another encoding, how to get it readable ? I tried various  combinations of decode and encode but nothing changes

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import os
import glob
import sys, codecs

path = '//server/share/folder/'

def get_exif_data(fname):
  ret = {}
  try:
    img = Image.open(fname)
    if hasattr( img, '_getexif' ):
      exifinfo = img._getexif()
    if exifinfo != None:
      for tag, value in exifinfo.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        if type(value) == 'str':
          ret[decoded] = value.encode('latin-1')
        else:
          ret[decoded] = value
  except IOError:
    print 'IOERROR ' + fname
  return ret

def scandirs(path):
  for currentFile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*') ):
    if os.path.isdir(currentFile):
        print '\ngot a directory: ' + currentFile + '\n'
        scandirs(currentFile)
    ext = os.path.splitext(currentFile)[1].lower()
    if ext not in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.jfif']:
      return 0
    print currentFile
    print get_exif_data(currentFile)

scandirs(path)
```

here a sample of the output, notice the encoded contents of MakerNote

```
#{'YResolution': (180, 1), 41985: 0, 'ResolutionUnit': 2, 41987: 0, 41988: (2272, 2272), 41990: 0, 'Make': 'Canon', 'Flash': 89, 41986: 0, 'DateTime': '2005:10:14 13:10:26', 'MeteringMode': 5, 'XResolution': (180, 1), 
#'MakerNote': '\x0e\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00.\x00\x00\x00\\\x04\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x04\x00\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00"\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x18\x05\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00$\x00\x00\x00 \x05\x00\x00\x13\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00h\x05\x00\x00\x06\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00p\x05\x00\x00\x07\x00\x02\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x90\x05\x00\x00\x08\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc6\xe5\x1b\x00\t\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\xa8\x05\x00\x00\x10\x00\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00!\x01\r\x00\x03\x00"\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x01@\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xaa\x02\xe3\x00 \x00c\x00\xc0\x00\x01\x00\x08 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xe0\x08\xe0\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xe3\x00\x1e\x01\xd7\x00$\x01\xdb\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00X\x00_\x00\xbd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xce\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x91\x01\x00\x00c\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\t\x00\xe0\x08\xa8\x06\xe0\x08\xd4\x00\x99\x01&\x00f\xfe\x00\x00\x9a\x01f\xfe\x00\x00\x9a\x01f\xfe\x00\x00\x9a\x01\xd7\xff\xd7\xff\xd7\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00)\x00)\x00)\x00I\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00IMG:PowerShot S45 JPEG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Firmware Version 1.00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\x00\t\x00]\x01[\x01Z\x01]\x01\\\x01\\\x01]\x01U\x01_\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00z\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\n\x00\xa7\x00\xda\x000\x00\x00\x00\xf9\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x00', 'ColorSpace': 1, 'ExifImageWidth': 2272, 'DateTimeDigitized': '2005:10:14 13:10:26', 'ApertureValue': (95, 32), 'UserComment': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'FocalPlaneYResolution': (1704000, 210), 'CompressedBitsPerPixel': (5, 1), 'SensingMethod': 2, 'FNumber': (28, 10), 'DateTimeOriginal': '2005:10:14 13:10:26', 'FocalLength': (227, 32), 'ComponentsConfiguration': '\x01\x02\x03\x00', 'FocalPlaneXResolution': (2272000, 280), 'ExifOffset': 196, 'ExifImageHeight': 1704, 'Model': 'Canon PowerShot S45', 'Orientation': 1, 'ExposureTime': (1, 60), 'FileSource': '\x03', 'MaxApertureValue': (95, 32), 'ExifInteroperabilityOffset': 1572, 'FlashPixVersion': '0100', 'FocalPlaneResolutionUnit': 2, 'YCbCrPositioning': 1, 'ExifVersion': '0220'}
```

EDIT: i managed the walking part but still struggle with the encoding

```
if isinstance(value, str):
  ret[decoded] = value.decode('utf-8')
```

error

```
Unexpected errorTraceback (most recent call last):: <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>
File "c:\python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 22: invalid start byte
```

Comment: If you want to (recursively) walk through a directory, why not use `os.walk`?

Comment: What is the `type()` of value if it's not a `str`?

Comment: the fields that are unreadable have type str, so i only try decoding/encoding on them

Comment: why did you start using utf-8? is there no specification for Exif content?

Comment: i have no control over the images and the exif in it, also don't know which encoding they are in, just trying to make them visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_images(arg, directory, files):
    for file_ in files:
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file_)
        if extension in ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png']:
            get_exif_data(os.path.join(directory, file_))

os.path.walk(path, find_image, None)
```

Comment: thanks for the walk sugegstion, now that part works, still struggling with the encoding part

Answer (score 0):

`scandirs` is returning once it encounters file w/ the "wrong" extension. Do you have such files in your directories? You just need to `continue`. If you want to traverse a tree use `os.walk` and then you don't need recursion.

If you want readable output, you probably want to `decode` you `str` object. Also, see last note below.

Various notes:

- put everything beside `Image.open` line into `else` clause
- check for `None` like this: `if exifinfo is None:`
- type-checking: `isinstance(value, str)`. This bit is important, I don't think that any of your encoding/decoding was ever executed, actually.

Cf.:

```
>>> type('st') == 'str'
False
```

Comment: thanks, i managed the walking part but still struggle with the encoding, pleaqe check my updated question

Comment: @peter: your `if` condition is wrong. this is not how you do type-checking!

Comment: do you mean my update ? if isinstance(value, str):
then what should i use ?